# How to update the NVIDIA Platform Controllers and framework driver?

Tags: frameworks, driver, nvidia

I downloaded the latest update of NVIDIA Platform Controllers and Framework driver from the drivereasy application on my PC and in order to install the driver, I went to device manager and selected to update the driver and chose the latest driver from my computer but it shows the error: Windows encountered a problem installing the drivers for your device.
[Image showing that the driver has been downloaded by drivereasy application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53qxk.png)
[Image showing that after trying to update the driver via device manager it doesnt accept it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSd4a.png)

Tried to update the NVIDIA Platform Controllers and Framework driver via drivereasy but failed.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your version of windows does not support this driver. if you know the manufacturer then you can check if your version of windows supports this driver. even if it says it was downloaded it doesn't mean it is supported.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I do understand it now. I have one last question, by mistake i uninstalled the realtek high definition audio driver and now i cannot find where and how to install it, do u know how to?

Comment: if you have windows 10 then you can do this. (it may not be limited to windows 10)
    You can go to Realtek official download website, search for Realtek audio driver for your system, and download it to your computer.
    After the download process completes, you can double-click the setup file and follow the instructions to install it. The Realtek HD Audio Manager software will be installed along.